# How to use an alternative end point to resolve cross origin issues

Tags: jquery, api

I am battling with the twitch TV challenge on free code camp. But I'm unable to get any response from my API call. 
So I used the alternative endpoint that was provided for the challenge

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var url= "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp";

  $.getJSON(url,function(data1){

    if(data1.stream===null){

      $("#fccStatus").html("Free Code Camp is Currently OFFLINE!");

    }

    else{

      $("#fccStatus").html("Free Code Camp is Currently ONLINE!");

    }

  });

  });
```

Still no result. 
Check my pen for more details. Only one API call is working.

https://codepen.io/Ojomiba/pen/EbRJEQ

Comment: json1 and data1 should have the same name as json1 store the return JSON

Comment: @iSZ  I've adjusted the code to add a client ID which is required for the twitch tv end point.

Comment: Now only one call is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve. Also you are required to use jsonP instead of json or your request will be blocked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/freecodecamp',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data){
        if(data.stream===null){
          console.log('no stream', data);
        }else{
          console.log('stream', data.stream);
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the $.getJSON method better and it is working with only one API call. So I decided to send you the link to my pen here https://codepen.io/Ojomiba/pen/EbRJEQ

Comment: Check it out. The free code camp call is working. But all subsequent calls are failing seemingly

Comment: @user20490 I just checked out your code pen link and the followerUrl is failing with a 400 error, it needs to be updated to [this](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/freecodecamp/follows/channels/?client_id=7slsxf0da18e4dn8rou1dw1ji1oxsca). I think you just need to swap streams for users.

Comment: Thanks iSZ. I used the first url call along with a static array of user names to make some head way.  Now that you've said it, I'll adjust my followerURL. Thanks  a lot!!

Comment: @user20490 no problem